# Delete multiple rows in PostgreSQL with Entity Framework using WHERE IN clause

Tags: c#, performance, entity-framework, postgresql

I have a postgresql database and what I am trying to do is remove a bunch of rows from a table in as few queries as possible. So looping is not a good option. I am using NPGSQL for the postgres driver.

I have the code below but it is not working.

```
        string[] namesToDelete = PromosReplies.
                         PromosRepliesLoaded.GroupBy(pr => pr.Name).
                         Select(r=>r.Key).ToArray();
        long[] repliesIdsToDelete = context.PromosReplies.
                                    Where(pr => namesToDelete.Contains(pr.Name)).
                                    Select(r => r.Idx).ToArray();
        if (repliesIdsToDelete.Length > 0)
        {
          foreach (var name in namesToDelete)
          {
           context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("DELETE FROM messages WHERE name = {0}", name);
          }
            string idToDelete = String.Join(",", repliesIdsToDelete);
            int result = context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(
                 "DELETE FROM message_translations WHERE idx IN ({0})",
                 repliesIdsToDelete);
```

I get a "ERROR: 22P02: invalid input syntax for integer:" error when trying to execute the last query. Is there a way to overcome this? If yes can something similar be done with first delete statement where I have to use a string?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**update**
I'm not working with EF, but here's the way to use array as parameter with Npgsql:

```
var cmd = NpgsqlCommand();
cmd.CommandText = "select * from test where id = any(@list)";
cmd.Connection = "**************************";
cmd.Parameters.Add("list", NpgsqlDbType.Array | NpgsqlDbType.Integer);
cmd.Connection.Open();
var r = cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

So I suppose in EF it would something like:

```
var par = new NpgsqlParameter("list", NpgsqlDbType.Array | NpgsqlDbType.Text);
var par.Value = namesToDelete;
int result1 = context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(
    "DELETE FROM messages WHERE name = any(@list)",
    par
);
```

**old** I don't like this one at all because it could lead to SQL injection:

```
int result1 = context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(
    String.Format(
        "DELETE FROM messages WHERE name in ({0})",
        String.Join(",", namesToDelete.Select(x => "'" + x + "'"))
    )
);

int result2 = context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(
    String.Format(
        "DELETE FROM message_translations WHERE idx in ({0})",
        String.Join(",", repliesIdsToDelete)
    )
);
```

I'm not an expert in EntityFramework, but I think when you use `context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(command, str)`, str is used as a parameter, so your command becomes `DELETE FROM message_translations WHERE idx in ('1, 2, 3, 4')` (note single quotes, `'1, 2, 3, 4'` is actually a string on server side).

You could use table-valued parameters if your DB was SQL server, may be it's possible to pass array as a parameter into PostgreSQL, have to try later.

Comment: @idipous Have you tried to pass string (not list)? changed the answer, check it

Comment: I wish I could push the upvote button more than once man. Thank you. IT worked on both cases. Much faster now! One question though. Why did String.Format do the trick in both cases?

Comment: @idipous added an short explanation

Comment: Thank you, I have tried passing an array as parameter but it did not work.

Comment: I tried using the new suggestion but there is no NpgsqlDbType.String. When I tried String or Varchar I got the following errors ERROR: 42883: operator does not exist: text = character varying[].

Comment: @idipous try `NpgsqlDbType.Text`, also use `name = any(@list)` in your where clause

Comment: I had dried Text to no avail but the any did the trick! This way (without using the format we are not having sql injection issues too). Thanks a lot

Comment: @idipous yes, that's whay I had to try to use array - I don't like the solution with format, but it was obvious one